# How to fix Node.js file pathing errors despite apparently correct path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access files multiple folders away from my script in Node.js. The nested structure is due tot the potentially long-running nature of my program, so simplifying this isn't an option.

My folder directory is as such:

```
assets
-reservations
--2018
---arriving
----0705.json
----...
---departing
----0705.json
----...
--templates
---wkday_arr_template.json
---...
-tidecharts
--2018
--...
-generatecalendar.js
```

To try to access 'wkday_arr_template.json' from 'generatecalendar.js' using the FS system, I call the access functions for

```
'./reservations/templates/wkday_arr_template.json'
```

When I do this, I get

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './reservations/templates/wkday_arr_template.json'
```

I have tried statically pathing from `C://`, going back to `assets`, and even tried using `__dirname`, however none of these had any effect.

Comment: have you tried `/reservations/templates/wkday_arr_template.json`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes - it produces the same output without the leading period. Same thing happens without the leading slash as well

Comment: To access a relative directory, we need to know where you're starting from, either what is the current directory (where your program was launched from) or what the module directory that you're trying to load this from which will be in the `__dirname` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please console.log(__dirname) and adjust your path accordingly.

Comment: adding ```__dirname + ``` to my call worked. Thank you